# How can I install HP printer(LaserJet P1007 ) driver in my Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: drivers, printing, hp, hplip

The PC is recognising my HP printer but I am still unable to print.
I have tried both the methods (Method 1 and 2) mentioned in this [site](https://sites.google.com/site/tipsandtricksforubuntu/printer-info/hplip-driver), but it is still not working. The terminal didn't complete installation by method 2, I waited for 4-5 hours hoping it will complete but it didn't.

Please help me find a solution

Comment: You've installed the non-free plugin that this printer needs?

Comment: Hey Tim! Please paste the output of `dpkg -l hplip` in your question by [edit]ing your question.